# Determining whether a given map is closed/a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology

I would like to solve the following problem:

> Let $X$ be the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes in the plane and let $f$ be the function from $X$ to the $x$-axis that sends all of the $y$-axis to the point $0$, and is the identity on all of the $x$-axis. Determine if $f$ is continuous, open, closed, and/or a quotient map.

So far what I've figured out is that it is continuous (it is a restriction of the canonical projection map onto the $x$-axis $\cong \mathbb{R}$) and it is not open (the set $U =\{0\} \times (0,1)$ is open in $X$, but $f(U)= \{ 0 \}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$). I have a feeling that it is not closed. If that's the case, I'm looking for an unbounded, closed set in $X$ with non-closed image, but I'm having trouble coming up with something.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is closed map. Note that $X$ is the union of two closed subset - namely $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$. Consider the intersection between $F$ and $x$-axis namely $F_x$ and the intersection between $F$ and $y$-axis namely $F_y$. Clearly $F_x$ and $F_y$ are closed and
$$f[F]=\begin{cases}F_x&\text{if }F_y=\varnothing\\ F_x\cup\{0\}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
so $f[F]$ is closed.

---

Also, $f$ is a quotient map. You can check that if $V\subset \Bbb{R}$ is a *any* subset, then
$$f^{-1}[V]=\begin{cases}V\times\{0\}&\text{if }0\notin V\\ V\times\{0\}\cup \{0\}\times \Bbb{R}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
so $V$ is open when $f^{-1}[V]$ is open - just consider the intersection between $f^{-1}[V]$ and the $x$-axis.

Comment: +1. Users might like to note that, more generally,  every closed surjective map between arbitrary topological spaces is a quotient map.